# Data from MySQL Database - Edit entry

Tags: php, html, mysql

I hope that someone can help me with a little issue. I have no idea how to solve that. For someone who works with MySQL and PHP it should be easy to explain I guess. Anyway here is what I need:

I created an admin interface with PHP. Inside the admin interface I have a table with entries from my database. So inside the table I can see the ID, username, first name, last name and so on from every single user.

[image]

Now on the right side you can see the text "Bearbeiten" which means "Edit" in English. If I click on edit I am redirected to my edit page. Problem ist, that the edit.php ist the same for every user. What I want now is, that if I click on "Bearbeiten" that I will be forwarded to the edit.php BUT that I am able to edit the specific user there.

For example if I click on "**Bearbeiten**" in the row where the user is with User ID 1 than I want to be redirected to `edit.php?id=1` so that I am able to edit only the selected profile.

Can someone help me? What do I need to do inside my code?
I would really appreciate your help!

EDIT:

Here is my table code at the user overview site:

```
<table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table bulk_action">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr class="headings">

                                                <th class="column-title">ID </th>
                                                <th class="column-title">Schule</th>
                                                <th class="column-title">Vorname </th>
                                                <th class="column-title">Nachname </th>
                                                <th class="column-title">Registriert am </th>
                                                <th class="column-title">Aktiv </th>
                                                <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr">Profil</span>
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="bulk-actions" colspan="7">
                                                    <a class="antoo" style="color:#fff; font-weight:500;">Mehrfachauswahl ( <span class="action-cnt"> </span> ) <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                                            </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <?php while ($row = $erg->fetch_assoc()) { ?> 
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="even pointer">
                                    <td class=" "><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                                    <td class=" "><?php echo $row['schule']; ?></td>
                                    <td class=" "><?php echo $row['firstname'];?></td>
                                    <td class=" "><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                                    <td class=" "><?php echo $row['registration']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="a-right a-right "><?php echo $row['active']; ?></td>
                                    <td class=" last"><a href="edit_profil_teacher.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Bearbeiten</a>
                                                    </td>
                                            </tr>           
                            <?php } ?>
              
                             </tbody>
                            <?php $erg->close(); ?> 
                                    </table>
```

Here is what I entered at the top of my edit page:

```
<?php
$user_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
?>
```

Problem right now is that URL at user overview page changed to edit.php?id= but that´s it. It does not select the correct ID. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Well my problem is I am not sure where to start? I believe it is possibe with PHP and maybe a $_GET function but I do not know where or how I should start

Comment: It is most definitely possible. You should research basic CRUD operations in PHP with `mysqli` or `pdo` and you should be able to figure it out from there. To answer you other question, yes you can pass in the `ID` of the item you are trying to edit with a GET parameter. A word of caution though, it'd be very easy to simply change which `ID` you are editing by changing the URL, so be sure to implement proper security.

Comment: *"`What` do I need to do inside my `code?`"* - Two operative words here being the first and the last in that sentence..., including the question mark - That's just it... ***"What code"?***

Comment: updated my question with my code! Hope that helps to help :)

Comment: @ChristophC. it should work now, no?

Comment: The thing is now, will the good people also need to provide you with codes such as [`UPDATE table SET col_x = 'abc' col_y = 'def' WHERE col_z = 'xxx'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)? Or, do you already have that? Edit: I guess you do ;-)

Comment: It is working now! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming in the listing page you are looping around a mysql result to generate the HTML, you need to add the `id` to the anchor tags `href` tag.

Code has been changed to use the $row['id'] from provided coded.

On the link for "Bearbeiten" change the:

```
<a href="edit.php">Bearbeiten</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Bearbeiten</a>
```

Change $id to whatever you're calling the PHP variable for the ID column, on your edit.php page you can then pull user details from the database for that user ID.

Comment: I was about to ask him why and @RiggsFolly fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for that fast help. There is just one thing I do not understand: "Change $id to whatever you're calling the PHP variable for the ID column, on your edit.php page"! What do you exactly mean by that? What do I have to change on the edit.php so that I knows which user it is?

Comment: Just changed it again, didnt see the missing `?id=<?php echo $id; ?>` first time. `edit.php` just needs to get the `id` from `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Hey Christoph C. -- I just meant to use the variable name you used to display the ID in the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Bearbeiten</a>
```

And then in the edit.php page at the top:

```
$user_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added your link code to my user.php where my table is and I added $user_id = (int)$_GET['id']; to my edit.page! Now when I scroll over the "Bearbeiten" link it changes to edit.php?id= but there is no ID. What am I missing?

Comment: You just need to make sure that $id is the variable name on the main user page for the users ID.

Answer (score 0):

Like members have already suggested, put this in a loop something like:

```
<?php
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 { 
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $name = $row['Name Eleternteil'];

?>
<td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Bearbeiten</a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

This shoulkd take you to the next page with the unique `ID` and then on the `edit.php` get the id and do whatever you want by simply using:

```
<?php
    $edit = $_GET['id'];
?>
```